# GetProfiles Issue When Accessing Hikvision Cameras Programmatically Via ONVIF

Tags: soap, onvif

PROBLEM:

I have a number of test cameras that I'm using in development of a Cocoa ONVIF driver. I have AXIS, Dahua and Hikvision (so far -more will be coming).

All of the cameras claim conformance to Profile S and Profile G.

The AXIS cameras are the only ones that are behaving as expected.

Most can return RTSP image data if I send a direct URI to them (which, I see, is how most "ONVIF" apps seem to work).

What I am trying to do, is use the "proper channels" to access these devices.

That means running the MANDATORY GetProfiles query, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
    <soap:Body>
        <trt:GetProfiles/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

That's textbook. Straight out of the ONVIF application programming guide. I'm using a REST injection app to test this, using POST. I have set up authentication as Basic, using a full admin user.

The issue is that Hikvision cameras consistently return an *"Optional Action Not Implemented"* fault, which is their way of saying "We don't like what you sent".

I should note that the Core commands, like "GetServices" and "GetCapabilities" work just fine.

There is precious little lessons learned stuff out there on ONVIF. I think it's a standard that is still struggling to stand up on its own.

The only thing I've seen out there is [this post](https://github.com/rvi/ONVIFCamera/issues/4).

That does not apply to me. The same issue happens when I use either WSDL version.

When I Wireshark the apps that can connect to the camera, all I see is that they directly send an RTSP URI. No mention of "GetProfiles".

My question is this an issue that anyone else has encountered?

If so, how was it solved? I am learning to loathe the ONVIF spec, as it gets real hard to find detailed packet descriptions.

Comment: Just a note: I have a question into Hikvision Tech Support. So far, crickets chirping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are posting all the requests to the same URI. `GetServices` and `GetCapabilities` belong to the Device management Service, while `GetProfiles` belongs to the Media Service, which could have a different URI (this is something you must verify with `GetServices`).

The ONVIF specs are abundant, I suggest you to start from the [ONVIF Application Programming  Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf). It gives you an idea about how to structure your application.

Comment: OK. I think I see one issue on my part. I don't think that I'm parsing the response to GetServices properly, so only the namespace URI is being returned. I will start there, and work through.

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thanks! I will greencheck your answer.

Comment: For the record, the mistake was on my part. I was incorrectly interpreting the GetServices call (I did actually read the API spec -I wouldn't have gotten this far if I hadn't). Thus, I was not providing the correct local path. AXIS uses the same path for everything, but Hikvision uses a different path for each namespace. That was why it was failing.